# Search range of int values using djapian

Tags: python, django, search, xapian

I'm using djapian as my search backend, and I'm looking to search for a range of values. For example:

```
query = 'comments:(0..10)'
Post.indexer.search(query)
```

would search for Posts with between 0 and 10 comments. I cannot find a way to do this in djapian, though I have found [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/djapian/issues/detail?id=20&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Opened%20Reporter%20Milestone%20Owner%20Stars%20Summary), and [patch](http://code.google.com/p/djapian/issues/attachmentText?id=20&aid=4747751738167112784&name=range_searches.diff&token=99beb96a502772720c0facaab7b195c9) to implement some kind of date range searching. I also found [this page](http://xapian.org/docs/valueranges.html) from the xapian official docs describing some kind of range query. However, I lack the knowledge to either formulate my own raw xapian query, and/or feed a raw xapian query into djapian. So help me SO, how can I query a djapian index for a range of int values.

Thanks,

Laurie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I worked it out. I'll leave the answer here for posterity.

The first thing to do is to attach a `NumberValueRangeProcessor` to the `QueryParser`. You can do this by extending the djapian `Indexer._get_query_parser`. Note the leading underscore. Below is a code snippet showing how I did it.

```
from djapian import Indexer
from xapian import NumberValueRangeProcessor

class RangeIndexer(Indexer)
    def _get_query_parser(self, *args, **kwargs):
        query_parser = Indexer._get_query_parser(self, *args, **kwargs)
        valno = self.free_values_start_number + 0
        nvrp = NumberValueRangeProcessor(valno, 'value_range:', True)
        query_parser.add_valuerangeprocessor(nvrp)
        return query_parser
```

Lines to note:

```
valno = self.free_values_start_number + 0
```

The `self.free_values_start_number` is an `int`, and used as the value no, it is the index of the first column where fields start being defined. I added `0` to this, to indicate that you should add the index of the field you want the range search to be for.

```
nvrp = NumberValueRangeProcessor(valno, 'value_range:', True)
```

We send `valno` to tell the processor what field to deal with. The `'value_range:'` indicates the prefix for the processor, so we can search by saying 'value_range:(0..100)'. The `True` simply indicates that the 'value_range:' should be treated as a prefix not a suffix.

```
query_parser.add_valuerangeprocessor(nvrp)
```

This simply adds the `NumberValueRangeProcessor` to the `QueryParser`.

Hope that helps anyone who has any problems with this matter. Note that you will need to add a new `NumberValueRangeProcessor` for each field you want to be able to range search.